# Facebook Authentication with MongoMapper

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, mongomapper

I am trying to integrate Facebook authentication into a Rails application with mongomapper and I am getting an error on the following method.  I think the error is in the first_or_initialize section because it is ActiveRecord query instead of mongomapper.

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.name = auth.info.name
  user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
  user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  user.save!
end
```

end

EDIT:
[image: Here is the terminal output when the error is thrown]
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat. I was able to create the user by changing  the first_or_initialize line to this:

```
first_or_create(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).tap do |user|
```

Comment: I ended up finding another solution entirely but I will try that next time.  Thank you!